# Object of native class in java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Is it possible to declare an object of a native class (in c++) in java (android sdk)?

Comment: not related to the question, but might help - Check on SWIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution would be to create a JNI lib that would serve as a communication layer between your Java and C++ code.

That Lib would need to :

1- Contain methods that receive your needed Java Objects as JObject. (lookup this post for how to use the jobject : [how to pass java class instance as a parameter to JNI method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468276/how-to-pass-java-class-instance-as-a-parameter-to-jni-method)

2- Request your C++ objects to your native code

3- Do whatever you need to do with both objects.

Hope it helps ;)

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Native classes which be declared and defined in c++.

However when you use JNI, you define a Java class with native method and generate C code from this to implement using `javah`

Answer (score 0):

No.  The only objects that Java recognizes are Java objects.

The JNI approach allows you to create a native *method* for a Java class, and a JNI method implemented in C / C++ can create other C / C++ objects.  However, there is no way that you can pass such an object back to Java so that the Java code can use it directly.